# Python: request with custom header fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some problems making a post request with a custom header.
I'm using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library and as endpoint [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), where you can get for a POST request a fake JSON back.

I call my script with

```
py request.py
```

// request.py

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

def postReqCustom( url, headers, data):
    print('Making request to: ', url)
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

    print('status code: ' + str(r.status_code))

    response = r.json()
    pprint(response)

def postReq( url, data):
    print('Making request to: ', url)
    r = requests.post(url, data=data)

    print('status code: ' + str(r.status_code))

    response = r.json()
    pprint(response)

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

data = {
            "title": "foo",
            "body": "bar",
            "userId": 1
            }
post_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

#postReq(post_url, data) #ok
postReqCustom(post_url, headers, data) #error
```

For `postReq` I don't get any errors(status code 201) but when I try `postReqCustom` with a custom header I'm getting following error:

```
Making request to:  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
status code: 500
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request.py", line 55, in <module>
    postReqCustom(post_url, headers, payload)
  File "request.py", line 24, in postReqCustom
    response = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\Samy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Samy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Samy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: `50X` errors usually indicate it is an error with server application and not something the client can do anything about. No guarantee! You may want to see if the server is operating correctly. Try again later.

Comment: The server works. I'm getting 500 because of the custom header I include in the request... Without the custom header there is a status code 201

Comment: A well-behaved server should respond with a `40X` error code for that. Why do assume the server should accept your custom header?

Comment: In the example in https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#how-to under the point "Creating a resource" there is also the same header which I send therefore it should work I think

Comment: As a side note, you really do need to read through the Quickstart Tutorial if you're going to use Requests effectively. And you also need to learn how to debug your requests—e.g., print out `r.request.body`, `r.request.headers`, etc. to make sure they were what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `data=data`. As [the docs explain](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), if you use this argument, and pass anything but a string,<sup>1</sup> it form-encodes your data, which looks like this:

```
title=foo&body=bar&userId=1
```

It also, by default, sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so everything works fine.

But if you override that header with `application/json`, now you're passing the server the body `title=foo&body=bar&userId=1` and telling it to decode that as JSON. Which of course fails, so it's not surprising that the server gives you an error.<sup>2</sup>

---

If you want your values to be JSON-encoded instead of form-encoded, use the `json` parameter, not the `data` parameter:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

This JSON-encodes your data, which looks like this:

```
{"title": "foo", "body": "bar", "userId": 1}
```

And it will also default the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, so everything will work. And of course if you override the same header with the same value, it will still work the same.

---

If you want to do your encoding manually and send whatever string you encoded, you can use `data`, but then you have to send a string. For example (taken right out of the same docs section):

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

---

<sub>1. Both Unicode `str` and encoded `bytes` and `bytes`-like types are treated as strings here, but this isn't explained in the quickstart tutorial.</sub>

<sub>2. Of course a real server should, and probably would, return a `400 Bad Request`, rather than trying to do something that doesn't make sense, getting an unexpected error, and just punting with a `500 Internal Server Error`.</sub>

Comment: Note: I would expect a well-behaved server to respond with a `400 Bad Request` for this kind of client mistake.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for bringing that up. I think 500 makes sense for a completely generic test server—but a real API server that returned a 500 here would be buggy. I added a footnote to that effect.

Answer (score -1):

after taking a gander at your code; I can say that you implemented custom headers properly. After taking a look at the service you are using to mock REST endpoints, it seems that it does not accept the application/json MIME type. Here's what's accepted by your endpoint:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

After changing the header dict in your snipped to "Content-Type" : "text/xml", things worked pretty well( Got a 201 ):

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

def postReqCustom( url, headers, data):
    print('Making request to: ', url)
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

    print('status code: ' + str(r.status_code))

    response = r.raise_for_status()
    pprint(response)

def postReq( url, data):
    print('Making request to: ', url)
    r = requests.post(url, data=data)

    print('status code: ' + str(r.status_code))

    response = r.json()
    pprint(response)

headers = {'content-type': 'application/xml'}

data = {
            "title": "foo",
            "body": "bar",
            "userId": 1
            }
post_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
postReqCustom(post_url, headers, data)
```

Comment: Downvote with no context? A 500 Response would be valid if the request payload was not of an accepted MIME type. A 400 response would be more applicable for improper payload structure